# Откуда вылез баг с задачами. setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Когда удаляю 1 задачу -- все хорошо, удаляю еще одну появляется та котрую удалял до этого.Нажимаю на галочку(handleStatusChange) появляются все три, как это решить

[image: Удаляю 3 задачу]

[image: Появляется ту котрую удалил]

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./scss/style.scss";
import todosArray from "./todosArray"
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Todo from "./components/Todo";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: todosArray};
        this.handleStatusChange = this.handleStatusChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleStatusChange(id) {
        let resultList = todosArray.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.completed = !todo.completed;
            }
            return todo;
        });
        this.setState({items: resultList});
    }

    handleDelete(id) {
        console.log(id);
        let resultList = todosArray.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
        this.setState({items: resultList});
        console.log(resultList)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <Header title={this.props.title} todos={this.state.items}/>
                <section className="todo-list">
                    {
                        this.state.items.map(todo =>
                            < Todo
                                key={todo.id}
                                id={todo.id}
                                title={todo.title}
                                completed={todo.completed}
                                onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange}
                                onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                </section>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

const todosArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Изучить JavaScript c Николаем",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Изучить React",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Написать приложение",
    completed: false
  }
];

export default todosArray;

[![Удаляю 3 задачу][1]][1]
```

[image: Появляется ту котру]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема где-то в этой строке:

```
let resultList = todosArray.filter(...
```

Поясню. Каждый раз удаляя пункт списка вы снова и снова берете свой начальный (полный) массив пунктов (`todosArray`). Итак, после удаления одного элемента вы фильтруете этот массив и записываете в состояние. Но `.filer` не изменяет массив `todosArray`, а возвращает новый (`todosArray` не изменился). Удаляя второй пункт вы опять берете полный массив и естественно пункт, который вы удалили до этого останется и вылезет обратно.

Как лучше сделать? Один из вариантов написать как-то так:

```
let resultList = todosArray = todosArray.filter(...
```

... но лучше делать так:

```
let resultList = this.state.items.filter(...
```

Answer (score 1):

В handleDelete и handleStatusChange обработчиках вы используете константу todosArray, а надо this.state.items

К примеру, здесь, let resultList = todosArray.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);

В результате вы каждый раз оперируйте не с состоянием, а с todosArray, который не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через splice:

```
handleDelete(id) {
    console.log(id);
    const resultList = [...this.state.items];
    resultList.splice(id,1);
    this.setState({items:resultList});
    console.log(resultList)
  }
```